# Append columns to an ADO Recordset

Tags: vb6, ado

I am attempting to add columns to an ADO recordset in VB6. I simply want to add 4 columns to the end of the table. It's a table we use constantly but we often delete all the data in it and refill it with the next information we want, basically just using it as a means to temporarily hold data.

I have found that since it is ADO I should be able to use the following:

```
 with rs
     .fields.append "column name", "enum dataType"
 end with
```

From reading and experimentation it seems that the recordset has to be closed in order to add the columns.

Here's my code:

```
rs.Open "MeterReads", DataEnvironment7.cnPTracker, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' 2019-11-4 Adding in a section to accomadate for days to depeletion
If gbEnableD2D Then
    bExists = False
    With rs
        For Each fField In rs.Fields
            If UCase(fField.Name) = UCase("eddB") Then
                bExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If bExists = False Then
            .Close
            .Fields.Append "eddB", adDate
            .Fields.Append "eddC", adDate
            .Fields.Append "eddM", adDate
            .Fields.Append "eddY", adDate
            .Open
        End If
    End With
End If
```

I would expect there to be additional columns added to my table. However, I can look at the table and see they aren't in there. I can see as I have closed the recordset. That it attempts to append the columns to it. However, I open the recordset back up and those columns disappear from the table. When I say they appear I mean using Microsoft Visual Basic's debug system. It basically has a section where it shows your variables and for objects it shows you the items inside and a bit more info. So I know it attempts it. But I cant seem to get it to retain it. Any thoughts or ideas on were I'm screwing up would be great.

Comment: I did find this 
Calling the fields.Append method for an open Recordset or a Recordset where the ActiveConnection property has been set, will cause a run-time error. You can only append fields to a Recordset that is not open and has not yet been connected to a data source. Typically, these are new Recordset objects that you create with the CreateRecordset method or by explicitly assigning a new Recordset object to an object variable.

which doesnt make me feel to hopeful. If this is accurate. Thoughts on being able to retain the information Without creating a new record set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to add the columns when you open the recordset by modifying how you retrieve the data.  Instead of using `rs.Open` with adCmdTable, use adCmdText with a `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT *, NULL AS eddB, NULL AS eddC, NULL AS eddM, NULL AS eddY FROM MeterReads
```

Comment: Thank you. What I ended up doing what just performing the sql query to add them so I could avoid messing with it at it worked just fine. Still unsure why the SQL could do it but not the built in functionailty couldnt.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify the structure of the table in your database, you can use the **Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security** library (add it to your Project from the Project menu > References). You can find the table you want to modify by iterating through the Catalog object's Tables collection. First create a Catalog object:

```
Dim objCatalog As ADOX.Catalog

' Create and Open Catalog
Set objCatalog = New ADOX.Catalog
Set objCatalog.ActiveConnection = DataEnvironment7.cnPTracker
```

I am assuming `DataEnvironment7.cnPTracker` is your current ADO Connection object.

Then iterate through Tables:

```
Dim objTable As ADOX.Table
Dim sTableName As String

sTableName = "Customers"

' Check if Table exists
For Each objTable In objCatalog.Tables

    If objTable.Name = sTableName Then
        ' Table found, return reference
        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Then, once you have the table, you can go through the Columns collection to see if it exists:

```
Dim objColumn As ADOX.Column
For Each objColumn In objTable.Columns
```

Finally, if you can't find the column, you can add it:

```
Set objColumn = New ADOX.Column
With objColumn
    .Name = "FieldName"
    .DefinedSize = 200
    .Type = adVarChar
End With

' Append the new field
objTable.Columns.Append objColumn
```

Comment: Is this built into the functionality as is? Or is it something that would need to be added?

Comment: These objects and methods are part of the ADOX library but you will need to integrate them in your code. As you can see from the examples I gave you it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: To expand on Étienne's answer. The **DDL** in _"ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL..."_ stand for [Data Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) and is an object-orientated, RDBMS-agnostic library.

Comment: I appreciate it but that would be a massive over haul of the entire system. So I like the suggestion is just not something feasible in my situation

Answer (score 0):

```
with rs
     .fields.append "column name", "enum dataType"
 end withrs.Open "MeterReads", DataEnvironment7.cnPTracker, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' 2019-11-4 Adding in a section to accomadate for days to depeletion
If gbEnableD2D Then
    bExists = False
    With rs
        For Each fField In rs.Fields
            If UCase(fField.Name) = UCase("eddB") Then
                bExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If bExists = False Then
            .Close
            .Fields.Append "eddB", adDate
            .Fields.Append "eddC", adDate
            .Fields.Append "eddM", adDate
            .Fields.Append "eddY", adDate
            .Open
        End If
    End With
End If
```